# How to render a Wordpress blog list to display below WP Bakery content

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

I am using the WP Bakery Page Builder plugin. On one of my pages, I am using this plugin to create a title along with some text. I then changed the template to a Blog template, when previewing my changes  I can see my posts displaying correctly however the title and paragraph built with the page builder is showing underneath the blog posts.

How can I change this, as I am unable to see the code for where the blog posts pull in within WP Admin.

[image]

Comment: How do you want to change that? Do you want to remove the excerpts completely? Then you might need to use *display:none* with CSS if there are no options in WP Bakery to do that.

Comment: I want the row below the blog posts to appear before the blog posts. This is the section that reads "An Agency of Free Thought"

Comment: This may or may not be possible using WP Bakery depending if both of those sections were made with WP Bakery. If they were you can drag them on top of each other to re-order them. If the below section is not part of WP Bakery then you will have to use custom CSS flexbox and it's order property to re-order your elements.

Comment: I was thinking the same - The blog articles are standard posts pulled in via the blog template - only the title and paragraph at the bottom of this page was built with WP Bakery.

Comment: Glad you have found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a copy of the grid.php file and moved the code that creates a loop to change where the code is being rendered.